# Is Mutual auth with aws api gateway possible?

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, tomcat7, aws-api-gateway, mutual-authentication

I have an application installed in tomcat which currently I am running on http.
Also I have used AWS API gateway to expose my application .
I want to implement mutual auth between aws api gateway and my api which we have created  .
Is there any document which I can refer.
Also is it possible to implement mutual authentication with AWS API gateway and my api.

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely possible by installing an SSL certificate in Tomcat and using the Client Certificate feature of API Gateway. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html

Comment: Thanks , but I am looking for a way where my server already have a certificate from different CA and Amazon API Gateway has different CA,So I am not sure whether server and client with different CA will work if AWS doesnt have my trusted CA in it

Answer (score 0):

The API Gateway server must use a certificate the AWS ACM issues.
The Gateway itself uses another AWS-generated certificate to authenticate with your backend.